# Mapping a Collection to Map and vise versa with Mapstruct

Tags: java, mapping, dto, mapstruct

I am using Mapstruct to handle boilerplate code of mapping one POJO to another.

Here is the DTO:

```
import java.util.Collection;

public class TestTO {
    String name;
    Collection<AttributeTO> attributes;
}
```

Here is the mapped POJO:

```
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    String name;
    Map<String, Attribute> attributes;
}
```

I am looking for an elegant way to handle the mapping between the `Map` and the `Collection`. Currently, I am using the `expression` attribute of the `@Mapping` annotation. Since `Attribute` references `Test` I am using a `CycleBreakingContext` from the "mapping with cycles" example.

```
@Mapping(target = "attributes", expression = "java(test.getAttributes().values().stream().map(a -> this.map(a, context)).collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList()))")
abstract TestTO map(Test test, @Context CycleBreakingContext context);
```

The interface also contains a method mapping `Attribute` to `AttributeTO` with the name `map`.

Is there a more elegant way to implement this conversion of a non-iterable `Map` to a `Collection`? My approach is working but has it's downsides. Refactoring, for instance, does not recognise code fragments in Strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about default mapper methods?

In your mapper interface you can provide default implementation instructing MapStruct on how to map given types, for example:

```
default Collection<Integer> mapAttributes(Map<String, Integer> attributes) {
    return attributes.values();
}
```

This method will be called whenever MapStruct tries to map from Map to Collection.

You are free to customize it as much as you want.

Comment: If I add this to my interface I get the following error during compilation: Can't generate mapping method from non-iterable type to iterable type.

Comment: That is strange, are you sure that you are adding it with the `default` keyword? Alternative to using the `default` is to have a util class and static methods on it (if your the mapping is stateless).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I used it wrong in the interface. My fault... The approach is the correct way.